# How to append a vector to a matrix in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to append a vector to a matrix in python. I tried `append` or `concatenate` methods but I didn't get the answer. I was previously working with Matlab and there I used this:

```
m = zeros(10, 4) % define my matrix, 10x4
v = ones(10, 1) % my vecto, 10x1
c = [m,v] % so simple! the result is: 10x5 (the vector added as the last column)
```

How can I do that in python using numpy?

Comment: Are you talking about C++ or Python? Python doesn't have vectors/arrays it has lists or dictionaries.

Comment: @IanAuld - He's referring to numpy arrays.

Comment: sorry, I add numpy to the question text.

Comment: I'm a little out of practice, but wouldn't that be `[m v]`, not `[m; v]`?

Comment: yes you're right! it was spelling error :)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You're looking for [`np.r_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) and [`np.c_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html#numpy.c_). (Think "column stack" and "row stack" (which are also functions) but with matlab-style range generations.)

Also see [`np.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html), [`np.vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html), [`np.hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html), [`np.dstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html), `np.row_stack`, `np.column_stack` etc.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
m = np.zeros((10, 4))
v = np.ones((10, 1))
c = np.c_[m, v]
```

Yields:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

This is also equivalent to `np.hstack([m, v])` or `np.column_stack([m, v])`

If you're not coming from matlab, `hstack` and `column_stack` probably seem much more readable and descriptive.  (And they're arguably better in this case for that reason.)

However, `np.c_` and `np.r_` have additional functionality that folks coming from matlab tend to expect. For example:

```
In [7]: np.r_[1:5, 2]
Out[7]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 2])
```

Or:

```
In [8]: np.c_[m, 0:10]
Out[8]:
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  4.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  5.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  6.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  7.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  8.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  9.]])
```

At any rate, for matlab folks, it's handy to know about `np.r_` and `np.c_` in addition to `vstack`, `hstack`, etc.

Comment: Ok, now it rather complete

Comment: 100% correct, but I would discourage the use of `c_` and `r_` generally, they look weird in python code seem to exist solely to mollycoddle users coming over from MATLAB.

Comment: @wim - Good point. I certainly agree that it's generally a good idea to avoid using them in long-lived code bases that are going to be maintained by multiple people.  However, they are very handy for interactive use and building up quick sequences.  I probably shouldn't have recommended them right off the bat, but I find I use them a lot more than I used to, at any rate.

Comment: @wim, @Joe, why don't you recommend `r_`/`c_` (other than readbility)?

Comment: @cyborg - Basically, it's not readable. If you're not familiar with numpy, what do you think `r_` would do? The second (and larger) problem is it's surprising. Python folks are used to indexing being used to retrieve some part of an object. Therefore, it's a bit confusing when indexing is used to create something unrelated to the parent (`np.r_`) object.

Comment: Yep, the syntax is unpythonic - look at the implementation of `np.lib.index_tricks.AxisConcatenator.__getitem__` to see just how bat-sheet insane it all is.  I'll admit I do use them in interactive mode (and I came over from matlab originally too), but in a script you should certainly use `np.concatenate` and friends

Comment: @cyborg - Also, there's the "slicing with a complex step" part, which is quite useful in interactive mode, but very confusing to newcomers.  For example `np.r_[:1:10j]` is equivalent to `np.linspace(0, 1, 10)`.

Comment: Sweet Jesus, they needed to use `sys._getframe().f_back.f_globals` in the index tricks implementation.  It's crazy stuff like this that must have made it take years of work to port numpy to python 3 ...  I just hope they have good unit tests.

Comment: @wim - Heh! Yeah, that implementation definitely delves a bit into "dark magic". For what it's worth, though, the numpy python3 problem was the difference in the C api's side of things, not the python side.  Regardless, though, numpy was ported to python3 pretty early on (2009, I think), but wasn't merged into the master branch until mid-2010 because they wanted to have a single codebase that supported both.  As far as tests go, numpy is _very_ well tested, and is flat-out the best maintained code base I've ever worked with, at any rate (though that's not saying much).

Answer (score 4):

In numpy it is similar:

```
>>> m=np.zeros((10,4))
>>> m
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> v=np.ones((10,1))
>>> v
array([[ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.]])

>>> np.c_[m,v]
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```